# How can you build a device that gives you remote access to a connected LAN? (Not VPN)

Tags: network, vpn, physical-access

I was wondering how a device (eg. RPi or similar board could be built/configured in a way that when you plug it to a LAN (or connect Wifi) it let's you remotely access the LAN (like VPN, but without the ports open on the main router) and then leave behind. I am thinking RPi in an laptop charger that has (*how strange?*) an ethernet cable connected, or an empty NAS case placed directly to others (*huh, since when do we have three NAS? Well whatever...*). Endless possibilities here.

Of course you'd have to have physical access to the targeted LAN but only for a couple of minutes. Possible white hat activities are: Testing if your client has a good IP-device surveillance system, if he/she checks for suspicious up/down connections, physical access pentesting without being physically there and so on.

I am imagening some sort of reversed VPN, as you don't need to open ports if your reaching out **to** a VPN-server... It can definitely be done (and exists probably already) but I am not googling correctly. I'd suppose a Unix distro on such a board is a good start, but are there opensource projects that eventually have done it? Or what protocols/packets could you use to achieve something similar?

Thanks for ideas or links, I appreciate everything, and if I posted in the wrong forum, place or whatever I could have possibly done wrong let me know,

Thanks again,

k3rn3lpan1c

Comment: Yes, you can easily make or buy these. I mean going to close this question as it currently sounds like a shopping question. Please clarify if that is not the case.

Comment: I'd rather not buy one, but get to know the technologies that are usually implemented in such devices... Since I can not even find these guys for sale (as pointed out in question, I am not googling correctly) it would be a great help if you or somebody just gave me a link to such a product or github-project page, since I need a proper name to find it and search on... Sorry for posting in this manner...

Comment: Suggest you rephrase with points such as "what packages/applications/tools would be necessary for various uses and situation?" You mention reverse-VPN, which is a start. Consider port-knocking, netcat, rsync (for data exfiltration), etc. I think you have the basis of a good question here, it just needs to be restructured to fit the style of SE, as @RoryAlsop has indicated.

Comment: I see that you have edited the question as Rory has asked, but I still feel that it is very broad. It feels like you are listing requirements or dreams and asking how to do it. What have you tried? What references or guides have you found? Basically, this site works best when you have already tried it yourself and have a question about a specific part of the question.